# Resemble helper does not output the mismatch percentage

Tags: codeceptjs, resemblejs

I installed the resemble package required by CodeceptJS. When running the test it does not output the mismatch percentage and does not save the comparison image in the diff folder specified. It only outputs the tolerance level at the end of the test. Any ideas on why this is happening?

I already re-downloaded the npm package and tried to debug index.js and resemble.js files in the node modules. it seems that when running it never actually compares the two images

```
This is part of my config file in CodeceptJS

  helpers: {
    WebDriverIO: {
      url: 'https://www.mydirtyhobby.com',
        windowSize: 'maximize',
      browser: 'chrome',
      restart: false,
      keepBrowserState: false,
      keepCookies: false
    },

    "ResembleHelper" : {
      "require": 'codeceptjs-resemblehelper',
      "screenshotFolder" : './output/',
      "baseFolder": './base_images/',
      "diffFolder": './diff_images/',

    }
  },
```

The mismatch percentage should be shown and the diff image should be saved in the specified folder. But instead it only outputs the Tolerance Level that I am setting in the test.

Comment: solved. the problem is that resemble helper for CodeceptJS does not work on Windows. use this helper on UNIX

Comment: Maybe different path should be used on Windows systems

Comment: maybe, not sure. I spoke a lot with the guy who wrote the helper and we couldn't identify exactly why it's not running on windows. anyway i just switched to Linux and everything is fine